# How to create an array with category ids order by the one that has the most recent post

Tags: categories

I can't find a proper solution to this.

I have an array of categories for example:

```
$slidercategories_array = array(3,5,6,9,10,11,12,23,24,27);
```

I need to reorder the array like this first the category with the most recent post, and last the category with the oldest post.

Any ideas will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$slidercategories_array = array(3,5,6,9,10,11,12,23,24,27);
$in = implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $slidercategories_array ) );
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    'SELECT tt.term_id, MAX(p.post_date) AS max_date FROM ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' AS tt '
    . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id'
    . ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p ON (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = %s)'
    . ' WHERE tt.term_id IN (' . $in . ') AND tt.taxonomy = %s'
    . ' GROUP BY tt.term_id'
    . ' ORDER BY max_date DESC'
    , 'post', 'publish', 'category' );
$slidercategories_sorted = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
```

Comment: After a few weeks in use I have noticed that the second category stays always the same!! any ideas why?

Comment: Can't think of anything off-hand. Have you tried assigning a new dummy post to the offending category to see if it moves to the front?

Comment: Ignore the above comment. This was another error.  Sorry to bother you...